Using TransformationFunction with Simplify
My Goal is to get t==x[t]/v from x[t]== v t. I first tried Reduce[expr,t], but message was shown(I guess because t is in x[t]).I made function named trans with ApplySides as below, finally to get x[t]/v. The question is when I use the function in Simplify function, the expected transform does not occur. Could I get corrected part concernig the last expression?
expr = x[t] == v t (*x[t]\[Equal]t v*)
Reduce[expr, t] (*message "This system cannot be solved...*) 
trans[e_] := ApplySides[#/v &, e]
trans[expr]  (*x[t]/v\[Equal]t*)
Simplify[expr, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {trans}]   (*How to get x[t]/v\[Equal]t ?*) 


DivideSides[expr, v]

Try: Solve[x == v t, t]

also show about Solve[expr /. x[t] -> z, t] /. z -> x[t]   https://i.sstatic.net/itrxKEoj.png

Thank you for your comments; The reason seems to be that x[t]/v==t is not simpler then x[t]=v t. If given targeted simpliciy, Simplify shows the expected result:expr=x[t]==v t;
tf[e_]:=ApplySides[#/v &, e];
cf[e_]:=(Depth[e]-5)^2; (target depth 5 given)
Simplify[expr,TransformationFunctions->{tf},ComplexityFunction->cf]
